# How can you determine if KendoUI Grid is in a grouped state?

Tags: user-interface, asp.net-mvc-4, grid, kendo-ui, grouping

I need to perform an action on my page when the KendoUI grid has been collapsed. I know that the dataBound event fires when the grid is grouped however this event is fired when the grid loads or gets sorted as well. Within my onDataBound event handler how can I tell if the grid is in a grouped state or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On [DataBound](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#databound) event you can check if the grid currently is grouped using the DataSource [group method](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#group):

```
function onDataBound(e) {
    gridDataSource = e.sender.dataSource;
    if (gridDataSource.group().length > 0) {
        //the grid is grouped
        debugger;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To get notified when a group is collapsed you can use delegate event such as:

```
$('#gridName tbody').on('click','.k-i-collapse',function(){
     console.log('Group collapsed!')
})
```

Comment: thanks - i just realized my question was confusing. i meant to write "grouped" not "collapsed"